# Asciidoctor/PDF - Add line breaks for replaced attributes

Tags: java, asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

We have the following template to generate a PDF:

```
== Overview

{dynamic_tables}
```

The `dynamic_tables` attribute shall be replaced with text that represents a table. It has to be dynamically generated, as we can't know how many tables and how many rows there are.

I tried to just pass in the text for the tables (also with `\n` for line breaks), but asciidoctorj always make on line out of it and therefore fails to render a table.

How do I insert line breaks into a value, that is then passed into an attribute like `{dynamic_tables}` to render line breaks? I tried a couple things (like `\n` or `+`) but they are just inlined as well (`\n` being "ignored").

Answer (score 0):

You will need a + and a line break. Within an attribute assignment, a single line break ends the assignment, but a backslash followed by a line break becomes an actual line break. So within an asciidoc file, try this:

```
:dynamic_tables: first entry + \
second entry + \
third entry
```

The asciidoc code

```
== Overview
{dynamic_tables}
```

should then render like

```
== Overview
first entry +
second entry +
third entry
```

However I don't know whether and how it is possible to assign multi-line values on command line or with the API.